# Highlight Arabic text using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to highlight the keyword used for search in the blog. So far i managed to used the following script http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight/demo_en.html

problem is when i try to use the same for Arabic it fails due to Unicode issue. Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gq4hkvgd/6/

```
    var val2 = "Per id";
  // var val2 = "النظر";
                var options = {
                    exact: "exact",
                    style_name_suffix:false,
                    keys:val2
                }
                $('.wrapper').SearchHighlight(options);
```

I looked for such example which can work for both english & arabic but could not find.

Possible solution might be in this link http://tiku.io/questions/1079426/using-regex-and-jquery-to-select-patterns-in-arabic-text

but i am not able to resolve  way this script to be modified to work with arabic version also.

Answer (score 2):

SearchHighlight has hard-coded assumptions about Latin-based text (such as regexAccent) and might even assume left-to-right (I didn't analyze the code carefully enough to tell). You might want to look for a search plugin that specifically supports non-Latin codepages.

Nevertheless, SearchHighlight appears to work with Arabic after making one small change:

> `exact: "partial",`

Answer (score 0):

To match the arabic letters with regex in JavaScript use:

```
[\u0600-\u06FF]
```